# Wordpress @import or enqueue and does this code make sense?

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

Just discovered that @import isn't the most efficient way of importing stylesheets experimenting with enqueue. Does this make sense, trying to import several parent stylesheets in various folders:

```
<?php
/**
 * Load the style sheet from the parent theme.
 *
 */
function theme_name_parent_styles() {

  // Enqueue the parent stylesheet
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '0.1', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-admin-style.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/thumbfx.css', array(), '1', 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/dynamic-css/options.css', array(), '1', 'all' );


  // Enqueue the parent rtl stylesheet
  if ( is_rtl() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-name-parent-style-rtl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rtl.css', array(), '0.1', 'all' );
  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_parent_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: Can you please give more information about your problem, or this is a code review request? About the code - you should use different handlers (the first parameter of the enqueue function) for the different scripts, otherwise the code looks OK and it is the correct way to include scripts in the site head.

Comment: Added this enqueue to my functions.php in child theme, since doing so my main font changed trying to get it back. It's a mystery...considering all style sheets are loaded.

Comment: Do you use font-face for your fonts and if yes, in which css file? Also, do you use css import somewhere, something like: @import url('/css/fonts.css')?

Comment: I removed @import as I read in Wordpress codex it's better to enqueue not import on a style.css in the child theme...so I added function.php to child with enqueue.

Comment: Your problem might be in the get_template_directory_uri() function - it returns the path of the parent theme when used in a child theme. Check [get_template_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) and [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Comment: Cool and by check it do you mean eliminate it? cross referencing your suggestion now...I'm fairly new to this function among others.

Comment: You have to use one of the two functions to include the files. If your files are in the main theme, you have to use get_template_directory_uri(). If you are enqueueing files from a child theme - get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). About the missing fonts - is it possible that you are missing some css file that contains your font-face?

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I now feel silly for not just following the wordpress codex and using their php code for enqueue http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes I got caught up with someone explaining it differently somewhere else and fudged it all up. Stick to the books! thanks for walking me thru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule: follow the wordpress codex

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-style')  );
}
```

Next time I will check the [source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) first.

Solved, thanks for the troubleshoot @m1ro.

Comment: I'm glad that you found my recent addition to the codex useful. Feel free to also check out the post I've done on this subject [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/164120/31545). +1 for adding your solution. Just remember to accept your own answer when the restriction expires